# How to use a specific database for a single test in django?

Tags: python, django, testing, tdd

Does anyone kno how to use a specific database for a single test in Django?

EDIT: At the moment, i'm using sqlite for testing, but, i want to use a mysql database for a specific test (def test_benchmark...), which will benchmark some sql statements.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *single test*?

Comment: If you're using a django testrunner it is building up and tearing down a test database every time you run your test suite. Having a database set up specifically to run your tests against is A Bad Idea™.

Comment: @PeteTinkler : unless you use SQLite for your project (which might not be a great idea IMHO) this "test database setup / teardown" dance really slows down your tests, and slow unittests are A Really Very Bad Idea(tm) - so using an in-memory SQLite db for tests (and your real engine, Postgres or whatever, for dev) might not be such "A Bad Idea" in the end. Unless of course you have to test code using some features that are not supported by SQLite... but then it's integration test, not unittest, isn' it ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any builtin way to do it - but I didn't look for it neither honestly. One possible (dirty) hack is to check what's in `sys.argv` in your settings (which is just another Python module) and have an alternate database settings for your particular test, ie:

```
# settings.py
import os, sys


DATABASES = {    
   'default': {
       'NAME': 'db_name',
        'ENGINE': 'your.engine',
        'HOST': 'server',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
    }
}

if "test" in sys.argv and "your-test-name" in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {    
         'default': {
            'NAME': 'other_db_name',
            'ENGINE': 'your.engine',
            'HOST': 'server',
            'USER': 'django',
            'PASSWORD': 'django',
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django you set the database in your settings.py file. The configuration should look something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': 'server',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
        'OPTIONS' : { "use_mars" : False,
                      "provider" : "SQLNCLI10",
                      "extra_params" : "MARS Connection=True"},

    }
}
```

Comment: And ? How does this answer the question exactly ?

Comment: A specific database specified in settings.py. Question answered.

Comment: AOK. And this was supposed to be an helpful answer ?

Comment: You may combine this with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#overriding-settings